# java.io.IOException: request to write '' bytes exceeds size in header of '' bytes for entry ''

Tags: java, apache-commons-io, gzipoutputstream

I am creating a `tar.Gzip` file using `GZIPOutputStream` and I have added an another logic in that if any Exception caught while compressing file then, my code will retry three times.

When I am throwing an `IOException` to test my retry logic it throwing a below Exception:
`java.io.IOException: request to write '4096' bytes exceeds size in header of '2644' bytes for entry 'Alldbtypes'`

I am getting Exception at line: `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, tarStream);`

```
private class CompressionStream extends GZIPOutputStream {
    // Use compression levels from the deflator class
    public CompressionStream(OutputStream out, int compressionLevel) throws IOException {
        super(out);
        def.setLevel(compressionLevel);
    }
}

public void createTAR(){
    boolean isSuccessful=false;
    int count = 0;
    int maxTries = 3;
    while(!isSuccessful) {
        InputStream inputStream =null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream =null;
        CompressionStream compressionStream=null;
        OutputStream md5OutputStream = null;
        TarArchiveOutputStream tarStream = null;
        try{
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(rawfile));
            File stagingPath = new File("C:\\Workarea\\6d22b6a3-564f-42b4-be83-9e1573a718cd\\b88beb62-aa65-4ad5-b46c-4f2e9c892259.tar.gz");
            boolean isDeleted = false;
            if(stagingPath.exists()){
                isDeleted =  stagingPath.delete();
                if(stagingPath.exists()){
                    try {
                        FileUtils.forceDelete(stagingPath);
                    }catch (IOException ex){
                        //ignore
                    }
                }
            }
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(stagingPath);
            if (isCompressionEnabled) {
                compressionStream = new
                        CompressionStream(outputStream, getCompressionLevel(om));
            }
            final MessageDigest outputDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md5OutputStream = new DigestOutputStream(isCompressionEnabled ? compressionStream : outputStream, outputDigest);
            tarStream = new TarArchiveOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(md5OutputStream));
            tarStream.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_GNU);
            tarStream.setBigNumberMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.BIGNUMBER_STAR);
            TarArchiveEntry entry = new TarArchiveEntry("Alldbtypes");
            entry.setSize(getOriginalSize());
            entry.setModTime(getLastModified().getMillis());
            tarStream.putArchiveEntry(entry);
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, tarStream);
            inputStream.close();
            tarStream.closeArchiveEntry();
            tarStream.finish();
            tarStream.close();
            String digest = Hex.encodeHexString(outputDigest.digest());
            setChecksum(digest);
            setIngested(DateTime.now());
            setOriginalSize(FileUtils.sizeOf(stagingPath));
            isSuccessful =true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (++count == maxTries) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(Exception("MD5 hash algo not installed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
            try {
                tarStream.flush();
                tarStream.finish();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(tarStream);
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(compressionStream);
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(md5OutputStream);
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Case solved. This Exception `java.io.IOException: request to write '4096' bytes exceeds size in header of '2644' bytes for entry 'Alldbtypes'` thrown when the size of the file that going to be zipped is incorrect.

```
TarArchiveEntry entry = new TarArchiveEntry("Alldbtypes");
entry.setSize(getOriginalSize());
```

In my code `getOriginalSize()` is getting updated again at the end so in retry the original size became change and original size is now zipped file size so it was throwing this Exception.

Comment: This solved my issue, I had this problem when I used a TarArchiveEntry constructor with preserverAbsolutePath set to true.
For some reason in this case you need to set the size of the TarArchiveEntry, and in case anyone is wondering if this is too difficult, it is not, you just need Files.size(filePath)