# JAVA Tar sending by ftp

Tags: java, spring, tar

I'm trying to send a tar file by ftp. here is the code i use

```
try ( DigestOutputStream dos = new DigestOutputStream( FTPClient.getConnectionOuputStream( ftpRequest ), messageDigest ) ) {
        TarFile.tar( dos, tarfileDatas, Constants.BUFFER_SIZE );
        tarMetadata.setDigest( "MD5" );
}
```

In some cases, i get this error :

```
parallel-processing-18 - error sending tar file by ftp, request to write '1051' bytes exceeds size in header of '1050' bytes for entry 'Archives/20200223_6035954984_MCR_0a058eb3012d402eaf9e7ed290c376bb_SOR.txt'
```

Could you please help me to improve my code ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.io.IOException: request to write '' bytes exceeds size in header of '' bytes for entry ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831004/java-io-ioexception-request-to-write-bytes-exceeds-size-in-header-of-byte)